# How to find line-endings of text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, line-breaks

I have a Python3 script that runs under Windows but can (depending on the user's choice) produce either Windows-Style `\r\n` line endings, or Linux-style `\n`.

```
if linux_style_endings:
    newline = '\n'
else:
    newline = None
with open(myfile, "w", newline=newline) as g:
    g.write("sometext\n")
```

Manual checks confirm that this works.

Now I want to write a unit test to confirm this.

**How can I get the line endings of a text file?**

(So this is not about ignoring the line endings, but actually finding out which are used.)

**What I have tried so far:**

The following will read the content and convert the line endings to the same values. It produces identical results with either line ending, so I cannot use it to check:

```
with open(myfile.txt, "r") as f:
    f.read()
```

The following [i]does[/i] show the line endings:

```
with open(output_fastq, "rb") as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text.splitlines(keepends=True))
```

This will return e.g. `[b'sometext\n']` for the linux line ends, and `[b'sometext\r\n']` for the windows line ends.

**Isn't there a more elegant way than producing a reference file and comparing the results of a binary `f.read().splitlines(keepends=True)`?**

Comment: I think you're stuck with writing a file, and reading it back in, then comparing it. If you didn't have to have `open()` inside your function (but you do, for the `newline` argument), you could perhaps have use something from the `io` module.  A few things to note:

Comment: - you can (probably should) use the `tempfile` module, so the temporary files are appropriately created.

Comment: - I don't see a need to use `text.splitlines(keepends=True)`. You can just directly compare the binary result from `f.read()` to a binary "string" that fits what you expect. For a unit test, you'd be writing a very small file, so that all fits fine within 10 bytes or so to compare with.

Comment: - your program/function (at the top) is Windows specific. Since you rely on `newline=None`, it will likely work incorrectly outside of a Windows environment. If you want to be more OS agnostic, use the Windows specific newline `'\r\n'` instead of `None`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you hope to simplify this. "The line endings that are used by this file" is not an actual property of files on disk; files only contain bytes, and any interpretation as text is up to programs. So you have to do *something* that examines the bytes of the file. The *entire point* of text mode is to *not have to care* about how the line endings are represented; if you do care, that's what binary mode is for. That said, for a simple test you can probably figure out what `text` should look like directly.